# Efficient way to create a large matrix in python from a table of interactions

Tags: python-3.x, performance, pandas, numpy, parallel-processing

I have a csv file in the following structure, indicating "interactions".

I need to convert this to a standard square matrix format so that I can use some other functions written for graphs (with igraph).

CSV file I would like to convert has ~106M rows in the following format

```
node1 node2 interaction strength
XYZ   ABC   0.74
XYZ   TAH   0.24
XYZ   ABA   0.3
ABC   TAH   0.42
... (node names are made up to show there is no pattern except node1 is ordered)
```

and standard format I would like to have this data has about 16K rows and 16K columns as follows:

```
    XYZ   ABC   ABA  TAH ...
XYZ 0     0.74  0.3  0
ABC 0.74  0     0    0.42
ABA 0.3   0     0    0
TAH 0     0.42  0    0
.
.
.
```

I do not necessarily need to have a dataframe in the end but I need to have row and column names noted in same order and save this final matrix as csv to somewhere.

What I tried is:

```
import pandas as pd
import progressbar

def list_uniqify(seq, idfun=None):
    # order preserving
    if idfun is None:
        def idfun(x): return x
    seen = {}
    result = []
    for item in seq:
        marker = idfun(item)
        # in old Python versions:
        # if seen.has_key(marker)
        # but in new ones:
        if marker in seen: continue
        seen[marker] = 1
        result.append(item)
    return result

data = pd.read_csv('./pipelines/cache/fr2/summa_fr2.csv', index_col=0)
names_ordered = helper.list_uniqify( data.iloc[:, 0].tolist() + data.iloc[:, 1].tolist() )

adj = pd.DataFrame(0, index=names_ordered, columns=names_ordered)

bar = progressbar.ProgressBar(maxval=data.shape[0]+1,
                              widgets=[progressbar.Bar('=', '[', ']'), ' ', progressbar.Percentage()])
bar.update(0)
bar.start()

print("Preparing output...")
for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    bar.update(i)
    adj.loc[data.iloc[i, 0], data.iloc[i, 1]] = data.iloc[i, 2]
    adj.loc[data.iloc[i, 1], data.iloc[i, 0]] = data.iloc[i, 2]
bar.finish()

print("Saving output...")
adj.to_csv("./data2_fr2.csv")
```

About 20-30 minutes in and I just got 1%, which means this would take about 2 days which is too long.

Is there anything can I do to fasten this process?

Note: I could parallelize this (8 cores, 15GB RAM, ~130GB SWAP)
but single core operation takes 15GB RAM, ~15GB SWAP already. I am not sure if this is a good idea or not. As no two processes would write on the same cell of dataframe, I wouldn't need to correct for the racing condition right?

Edit: Below are speed tests for suggested functions, they are amazingly better than implemented loop (that took ~34 seconds for 50K...)

```
speeds in seconds for 250K, 500K, 1M rows:
pivot_table: 0.029901999999999873, 0.031084000000000334, 0.0320750000000003
crosstab: 0.023093999999999948, 0.021742999999999846, 0.021409000000000233
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using pd.crosstab:

```
pd.crosstab(df['node1'],df['node2'],df['interaction'],aggfunc='first').fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
node2  ABA   ABC   TAH
node1                 
ABC    0.0  0.00  0.42
XYZ    0.3  0.74  0.24
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how this works so fast? Performance improvement is amazing. Do they just change formatting of the file without touching the values?

Comment: It is using vectorized operations with consecutive use of memory.  Pandas/numpy magic.  I can not explain it in any more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need `.pivot_table` and then to reindex the columns (and rows which get changed), filling missing values with 0.

```
import pandas as pd

df2 = (pd.pivot_table(df, index='node1', columns='node2', values='interaction_strength')
         .reindex(df.node1.drop_duplicates())
         .reindex(df.node1.drop_duplicates(), axis=1)
         .fillna(0))
df2.index.name=None
df2.columns.name=None
```

Output:

```
     XYZ   ABC
XYZ  0.0  0.74
ABC  0.0  0.00
```

Comment: is this the actual output you got, because its not symmetric? (I will speed test all approaches suggested here and write the result in the end)

Comment: @ÖzgenEren This is based on the sample you provided, which does not have a `node1 = ABC` with `node2 = XYZ` row, which is why it's not symmetric. However, if you only have data to create the upper triangle of your `DataFrame` then you can easily mirror it across the diagonal.